# Unable to get the Slider in IE9 using input type=Range using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slider

I am trying to make the Slider using the AngularJS. I am not able to get slider in IE. 
I tried third party APIs like uislider and all.But not able to do make it work.
There is one Github library like RanglerSlider [RangeSlider](https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js) :Which is dependent on Jquery library.I am not sure how it can embedded in AngluarJS code.

I have created JSFiddle for the same. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vijayallagi/wfffv70a/2/)

**HTML Code**

```
 <table class="table-responsive inputClass " >  
       <tr ng-repeat="ldcInput in inputLDC">
           <td> {{ ldcInput.name }} </td>
           <td><input ng-model="ldcInput.value" type="range" min="{{ldcInput.minValue}}" max="{{ldcInput.maxValue}}" step={{ldcInput.step}}  precision='2' value="{ldcInput.value}}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Please help this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its alternate , if your angular js is finally not working.

Without plugin, You can't get working in IE 9

http://wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html

Type range is only supported in IE 10+

I always used this Plugin **Ion.RangeSlider**.

Cross-browser: Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox 3.6+, Opera 12+, Safari 5+, Internet Explorer 8+

http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

Comment: Thanks.But I am trying embed in angularjs code which is already running.

Comment: Ion.RangeSlider has angular support. Look here: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/215